# Winter Bash 2019 Hats Don't Appear in Chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

Apparently Winter Bash [hats are supposed to appear in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211772/282094), but [they do not](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob).

[image: Winter Bash Hats - Profile vs. Chat]

Comment: This happens every winter bash :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hats should now be working in chat. You will need to refresh the page if the page was previously loaded.

Comment: Working on all three Chat Servers. Thanks.